# Prove the inequality $(e^x-1)\ln(1+x)>x^2, x>0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove the inequality $(e^x -1)\ln(1+x)>x^2, x>0$

My steps so far:

$(e^x-1)\ln(1+x) > \ln(e^{x^2})$

$(e^x-1)(1+x) > e^{x^2}$

$e^x+xe^x-x-1>e^{x^2}$

Are the steps correct, and if yes what should I do next? Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about taylor expansion yet?

Comment: Second step seems off ... you should be getting $(1+x)^{e^x-1}$ in the LHS.

Comment: $e^x-1>\frac{x(1+x)}2$ for all $x>0$ and for $x>4$, $\ln(1+x)>\frac{2x}{1+x}$ and in (0,4) ....

Comment: $$\ln(1+x) \geq \frac{x}{1+x}$$ you meant to say, or?

Comment: @Diger if you are asking me, then sort of no. If you took that inequality then you'd get $x^2/2$ on the RHS.

Comment: Ok, I see. That's why you split the interval at $4$.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750387/prove-forall-x-0-that-ex-1-ln1-x-x2?noredirect=1 for a nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $e^x-1 \geq x+x^2/2$, you'll find
$$(e^x-1)\log(1+x)-x^2 \geq x(1+x/2)\log(1+x)-x^2$$
and since $x> 0$, it suffices to check $$\log(1+x) - \frac{x}{1+x/2} = \log(1+x) - \left(2 - \frac{4}{x+2}\right) \geq 0\,.$$
Equality holds at $x=0$, while you have (deriving with respect to $x$)
$$\frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{4}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{x^2}{(1+x)(x+2)^2} > 0 $$
for $x>0$.

Comment: +1 The question asked for hints, and this answer gives more than hints. I guess we can’t complain. But if our aim is to educate OP, and not just present a nice proof, then I think we should emphasise what order we are going in and what we know or don’t know at each step. OP clearly has trouble with this, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, the duplicate target has the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say: that's partly indeed true, but if he clearly has trouble rearranging terms and exponentiating a product, I'm not sure it is constructive to have endless discussions about what steps are eligible and which not, let alone the comment section gets flooded. I believe he has to think about it, and if he is stuck has to look a step further in the solution. I'm happy to answer any questions, about the way I approach it, and what I'm doing here and what not. But I always think answers are good, because you can set your own pace.

Comment: @Diger I assume i need to just know that ex−1≥x+x2/2 ? And if so, do you know where can find a list of all similar axioms to prove similar questions?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a list, but for the most important elementary functions, such as
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$$ you should just memorize these expansions; you will need to use them over and over again anyway.

Comment: @Diger thank you! Will do

Comment: @Diger Hello again, sorry to bother you. I have 2 questions: in exp(x) expansion why do we use first 3 terms of the expansion, and why do we ommit the first term, 1? Or does the -1 in the ex−1 eliminate the first term? And why is it not x−1,x2/2−1 in the 2nd and 3rd term? And 2nd thing, in the equation after "it suffices to check", where does the (2−(4/x+2)) come from on the RHS?And am i right in assuming that second term on the LHS comes from dividing x2 by x(1+x/2)? And if it's even possible, can you elaborate on the last equation? Both all the terms and how >= turned to > –

Comment: 1) You bring the $1$ to the other side, so, of course, exp-1, does not contain $1$ on the RHS anymore. I'm not sure I understand your question about x-1/x2/2-1. It is $$e^x=1+x+x^2/2 + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
and you neglect the positive sum-term. Then you bring the $1$ to the LHS.
2) Just simplify $$2-\frac{4}{x+2}$$ and bring everything ontop of a common denominator and you'll notice a familiar expression.
3) Yes the second term comes from factoring out $x(x/2+1)$; this term is positive, so you can neglect it in proving your inequality.

Comment: 4) In the last equation, the idea is the following: You want to show $$f(x) \geq 0 \, ,$$ which appears kind of difficult. However, we know $f(0)=0$ and so it can be written as $$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'(t) \, {\rm d}t \geq 0\,. $$ Hence, if we can show $$f'(t)\geq 0$$ for all $t$, then clearly the integral will be positive as well. Finally $f'(t)=0$ only at $t=0$ and $f'(t)>0$ for $t>0$, that's how the $>$ and $\geq$ come into play.

Comment: @Diger Thank you so much for the thourough explanation! Clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps seem very questionable.

Your first step is:

\begin{equation}
(e^x – 1) \ln(1+x) > \ln(e^{x^2})
\end{equation}

This is equivalent to the statement you are trying to prove, so you do not yet know if is true. You can use this as the new “target” for your proof, but you must be very clear that this is what you are doing. Instead, you simply wrote out the statement without explanation, implying that it is in fact true.

Your next step is:

\begin{equation}
(e^x – 1)(1 + x) > e^{x^2}
\end{equation}

It looks like you have taken the exponential of both sides. But, on the left hand side, you *should* get this instead:

\begin{align}
e^{(e^x – 1) \ln(1 + x)} &= \left (e^{\ln(1 + x)} \right)^{(e^x – 1)} \\
&= (1 + x)^{(e^x - 1)}.
\end{align}